# Ubuntu booted to tty. No GUI. "pkcs#7 signature not signed with a trusted key"

Tags: boot, command-line, gui, tty

While running ubuntu 18.04, I was running out of ram. So I decided to end some programs from the system monitor. But I ended some essential service then blank screen appears. I rebooted the system and it led me to tty. For those who don`t know, tty stands for Teletype. It is basically a non-graphical version of the whole system. I can still login and access the terminal but no GUI.

[image: NOT MY PC. Got the image from google]

Before , I got an error of `pkcs#7 signature not signed with a trusted key`. I ran `dpkg--Repair broken packages` (something I have found on forums) from recovery mode. But the error was not solved. Only the above stated line was gone.

**Edit**:- After a lot of searching, I tried to reinstall gdm3 and it solved the error. You can check my answer below.

Comment: Have you tried ctrl+alt+f1 or any of the function buttons?

Comment: Hit `Ctrl + Alt + F7` and see if it loads the GUI.

Comment: Terminating GDM seems unrelated to package errors. Seems like there is more going on than the question describes, which makes it unlikely to help future searchers.

Comment: I have solved the error. I reinstalled gdm3 and everything was back on. If you say so, I would edit the question and explain in detail.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution. I reinstalled and reconfigured gdm3 and it automatically started.
Reinstall gdm3:-
`sudo apt-get install --reinstall gdm3`
`sudo dpkg-reconfigure gdm`